# Is there a way to create instances of child class in parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I'm not sure if I'm explaining it correctly so I'll explain through an example.

```
public class ParentClass{
    public static ArrayList<ParentClass> generateInstances(int count){
        ArrayList<ParentClass> array = new ArrayList<ParentClass>();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            array.add(new this.getClass());
        return array;
    }
}

public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{

}    


public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{

}

public class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass{

}

public class ChildClass3 extends ParentClass{

}
```

So I have a class that has a lot of child classes. Somewhere else I would like to be able to create a set amount of each of the child classes. So I thought I'd make a function that would return just that. Is there a way for me to not have to implement `generateInstances()` in each of them, only in `ParentClass`.

Comment: I'm not sure about your understanding of Parent <-> Child relation... Normally it is solved by inheritence and "extends". You missed "extends" keyword. Was it intentionally?

Comment: It wasn't intentional, I fixed it

Comment: Parent classes not knowing about their subclasses is kind of the point. Also, a subclass may need additional info to create. You will need to at least add a method for single instance creation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this + remove "static" from the method. static methods don't know anything about the current object - "this"

```
 public class test {

    public ArrayList<test> generateInstances(int count) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        ArrayList<test> array = new ArrayList<test>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            array.add(this.getClass().newInstance());
        }
        return array;
    }

    static class child1 extends test {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "child1";
        }
    }

    static class child2 extends test {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "child2";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        child1 child1 = new child1();

        ArrayList<test> array = child1.generateInstances(2);

        array.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));

        child2 child2 = new child2();

        ArrayList<test> array2 = child2.generateInstances(3);

        array2.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
    }

}

> Task :Core:test.main()
child1
child1
child2
child2
child2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
22:18:05: Task execution finished 'test.main()'.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57471', transport: 'socket'
```